# Javascript for "show all dropdown" on datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I created a hidden table row (`id="table-row-span"`) which is hidden until triggered by clicking on a checkbox (`id="select_all"`). At this point the previously hidden row is shown and says "All entries shown on this page are selected. Select all entries in this table."

I'm looking for a script that when "all" entries in the dropbox is clicked by the user then every row appears and it appears as checkmarked. A screenshot ais shown as well. Any help would be great thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, I think this is the general idea

http://output.jsbin.com/fuwole

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Select All</title>
    <style>
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 500px;
      }
      table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid #444444;
      }
      #all_selected, #none_selected, #some_selected {
        color: #0000ff;
      }
      #all_selected, #some_selected {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
    // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705478/javascript-for-show-all-dropdown-on-datatable/39708801#39708801
    $(function() {
      // the user checks the "check all"
      $('#check_all').click(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
          // check all rows
          $('.data .checked').prop('checked', true);
          // show the correct message
          $('.message').hide();
          $('#all_selected').show();
        }
        else {
          // uncheck all rows
          $('.data .checked').prop('checked', false);
          $('.message').hide();
          $('#none_selected').show();
        }
      });
      // the user checks a data checkbox
      $('.data .checked').click(function() {
        // count how many are checked
        var rowsChecked = $('.data .checked:checked').length;
        var totalRows = $('.data .checked').length;
        if(rowsChecked == 0) {
          $('.message').hide();
          $('#none_selected').show();
          $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else if(rowsChecked == totalRows) {
          $('.message').hide();
          $('#all_selected').show();
          // let's also check the check all
          $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
        }
        else {
          $('.message').hide();
          $('#some_selected').show();
          $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: left"> <input id="check_all" type="checkbox"/> </th>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Type </th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="all_selected" class="message">
        <td colspan="3"> All entries shown on this page are selected </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="none_selected" class="message">
        <td colspan="3"> Select all entries in this table </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="some_selected" class="message">
        <td colspan="3">Some are checked &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="data">
        <td> <input class="checked" type="checkbox"/> </td>
        <td> Row 1 </td>
        <td> Type 1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data">
        <td> <input class="checked" type="checkbox"/> </td>
        <td> Row 2 </td>
        <td> Type 2 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data">
        <td> <input class="checked" type="checkbox"/> </td>
        <td> Row 3 </td>
        <td> Type 3 </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but is there a way to click on the text to show all table rows since the table is defaulted only to show 10 unless you click 25, 50, or all. Then with that click, the dropdown below the table that lets you select how many rows to display shows "all" and the checkbox (id="select_all") is clicked showing all rows as marked.